# How to create more complex types in graphql using code first approach

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Hello I'm trying to create `field` for mutation which is array of objects. Code looks like this:

```js
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

type ChainToAddress = {
  chain: string;
  address: string;
};

@InputType()
export class CreateONSInput {
  @Field()
  ons: string;

  @Field(type => [ChainToAddress])
  chainAddressess: ChainToAddress;
}
```

Currently is throwing following error:

`'ChainToAddress' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Any idea how to make it work, tried with interfaces / type but somehow not able to manage it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `InputType`/`ObjectType` out of your nested interface to make it work.

```js
@InputType()
class ChainToAddress {
  @Field()
  chain: string;
  @Field()
  address: string;
};

@InputType()
export class CreateONSInput {
  @Field()
  ons: string;

  @Field(type => [ChainToAddress])
  chainAddressess: ChainToAddress[];
}
```